# Diretiva vuejs para atualizar valor em outro campo

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Olá, sou novo em vuejs, estou montando um sisteminha para calcular o peso de um produto... Tenho um combobox do vuetify onde vai disponibilizar o nome do produto, (eu fiz um array de objeto, nome:'nome',valor:99) em baixo em uma tag h4 quero passar o valor, alguem sabe como fazer isso ?

```js
<h2>Selecione o produto</h2>
<v-combobox
  :items="produtos"
  item-value="produtos"
  item-text="nome"
  id="prod">
</v-combobox>

<h4 >Valor: {{produtos.valor}}</h4>
<h2>Digite o peso do produto:</h2>
<v-text-field></v-text-field>
<h4>Valor final {{produtos.valor}}</h4>
```

```js
data: {
  nomesCli: [
    'Felipe',
    'luan'
  ],
  produtos: [
    {nome: 'Costela 481' , valor: 99},
    {nome: 'Picanha angus' , valor: 120},
    {nome: 'Contra filé' , valor: 150},
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

bom dia,

Está a usar a notação de um objecto num array.
Ou seja, penso que tem de escolher o

```
{{produtos[0].valor}}
```

ou faz então faz um `v-for` para os produtos todos:

```
<div v-for="(produto, i) in produtos" :key="i">
  <h4>{{ produto[i].valor }}</h4>
</div>
```

Espero que ajude =)